# How to implement simple traffic shaping in go

Tags: multithreading, go, rate

I am trying as an exercise to implement simple traffic shaper in go.

The API is:
push(int): puts an int in the shaper
out(): outputs 1 or more int(s) from the shaper.

push is called by the clients and the rate can't be controlled.
out is called roughly every 1ms and can output 1 or more ints and is trying to maintain a constant out put rate of r ints per 1s but can output more if the intrnal buffer of the shaper is in danger of getting filled up. However the output should be as uniform as possible. For example:
Out: 1 1 2 2 2 1 is better than
Out: 1 1 5 1 1

since the second example is bursty (there's an output of 5 ints).

I have an idea of how to do this using leaky bucket algorithm.

My question:
How to implement in Go that output is called semi-regularly roughly at 1ms ticks?

Comment: Have you attempted this using a "leaky bucket" algorithm? What issues did you encounter?

Comment: This question seems to be asking for a complete implementation. Can you narrow it down to a single question/issue that might have a correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to implement in Go that output is called semi-regularly roughly at 1ms ticks?

Use the standard [time.Ticker](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Ticker), configured to flush output [every 1 millisecond](https://play.golang.org/p/Ic9FiHsOrw_L).

Comment: Thanks Jesse, exactly what I was looking for.